# How to display cols next to each other after mapping in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have this code that maps and displays my website's posts from an array.

```
import articleContent from '../data/articleContent';

const ArticlesList = () => (
  <>
    <ArticlesStyle>
      <h1 className="article-h1">Nasze artykuły</h1>
        {articleContent.map((article, key) =>
          <Link className="article-link" key={key} to={`/artykul/${article.name}`}>  
            <Row className="align-items-center text-center">
              <Col xs={4} md={5}>
                <h2 style={{ color: '#14B2E6' }}>{article.title}</h2>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="align-items-center text-center">  
              <Col className="text-left" xs={8} md={5}>
                <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>{article.content[0].substring(0, 150)}...</p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Link>
        )}
    </ArticlesStyle>
  </>
)
```

My goal is to automatically display two posts in one row (so two columns in a row I guess) on PC display and one post in a row on mobile. I tried to make some small adjustments to make it work, but I am clueless now.

This is how it looks now on PC, I can't get rid of this **marked area** - I think it's an issue related to **display: flex;**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to solve my own problem.

First of all I added outer (outer to .map function) Row and Col. I wrapped everything inside of .map function into Container.

```
const ArticlesList = () => (
  <>
    <ArticlesStyle>
      <Row>
        <Col className="article-list-grid">
          {articleContent.map((article, key) =>
            <Container className="wrapper">
              <Link className="article-link" key={key} to={`/artykul/${article.name}`}>  
                <Row className="align-items-center text-center">
                  <Col xs={true} md={true}>
                    <h2 style={{ color: '#14B2E6' }}>{article.title}</h2>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="align-items-center text-center">  
                  <Col xs={true} md={true}>
                    <p style={{ color: 'black' }}>{article.content[0].substring(0, 150)}...</p>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Link>
            </Container>
          )}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </ArticlesStyle>
  </>
)
```

After that everything comes to styling which looks like this:

```
const ArticlesStyle = styled.div`
    .article-list-grid {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .wrapper {
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            flex: 100%;
        }
        @media (min-width: 900px) {
            flex: 50%;
        }
    }

    .article-link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
`;
```

The most important thing here is **flex: 50%** on PC screens which result with 2 columns in a row. Everything looks as I wanted right now:

PC

[image]

MOBILE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS-grid for this. For web make the number of column 2 and then by using media queries in CSS you can make the number of column 1 in case of mobile width.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Can't I somehow manage to setup it in just react-bootstrap?